# Javascript - Return json from fetch in an Object

Tags: json, object, python-requests, fetch

I'm trying to make an application to get the recipes from https://edamam.com and I'm using fetch and Request object.
I need to make 3 request, and i thought that most beautiful way for do it is make an Object and a method that return the  data in JSON.
I declarated into constructor a variable called this.dataJson, and i want to save there the data in JSON from the response. For that purpose i use this.
The problem is that i have a undefined variable.

```
.then( data => {this.dataJson=data;
    console.log(data)} )
```

This is all my code.

```
class Recipe{
  constructor(url){
    this.url=url;
    this.dataJson;
    this.response;
    
  }
  getJson(){
    var obj;
    fetch(new Request(this.url,{method: 'GET'}))
    .then( response => response.json())
    .then( data => {this.dataJson=data;
    console.log(data)} )
    .catch( e => console.error( 'Something went wrong' ) );
    
  }
  getData(){
    console.log("NO UNDFEIND"+this.dataJson);
  }
  
}
const pa= new Recipe('https://api.edamam.com/search?...');
pa.getJson();
pa.getData();
```

I'm new studying OOP in JS and more new in Fetch requests...
If you guys can help me... Thanks very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: On an online site you press the "Order this pizza" button, and then look surprised when your plate is still empty. You cannot expect a future result to be available now. Check the suggested link for more information and how to get it done *asynchronously*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using `async-await` (and a placeholder API):

```js
class Recipe {
  constructor(url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.dataJson;
    this.response;

  }
  // the async keyword ensures that this function returns
  // a Promise object -> we can use .then() later (1)
  async getJson() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(new Request(this.url, {
        method: 'GET'
      }))
      const json = await response.json()
      this.dataJson = json
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Something went wrong', e)
    }
  }
  getData() {
    console.log("NO UNDFEIND:", this.dataJson);
  }

}
const pa = new Recipe('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
// 1 - here we can use the "then", as pa.getJson() returns
// a Promise object
pa.getJson()
  .then(() => {
    pa.getData()
  });
```

If we want to stay closer to your code, then:

```js
class Recipe {
  constructor(url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.dataJson;
    this.response;

  }
  getJson() {
    // var obj; // not needed
    // the "fetch" always returns a Promise object
    return fetch(new Request(this.url, { // return the fetch!
        method: 'GET'
      }))
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.dataJson = data;
        // console.log(data) // not needed
      })
      .catch(e => console.error('Something went wrong'));

  }
  getData() {
    console.log("NO UNDFEIND:", this.dataJson); // different syntax here
  }

}
const pa = new Recipe('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');

// using "then", because the "fetch" returned a Promise object
pa.getJson()
  .then(() => {
    pa.getData();
  });
```

The problem with your original code is that you initiate the request (`pa.getJson()`) and then immediately (on the next line) you want to read the data (`pa.getData()`). `pa.getData()` is called **synchronously** (so it happens in milliseconds), but the request is **asynchronous** - the data needs time to arrive (probably hundreds of milliseconds) - so, it's not there when you try to read it (it simply hasn't arrived yet).

To avoid this you have to use a technique to handle this **asynchronous** nature of the request:

- use a callback function (blee - so last decade)
- use a **Promise** object with `then()` (much better) or `async-await` (yeee!)

and call the `pa.getData()` when the response has arrived (inside the callback function, in the `then()` or after `await`ing the result).